# How to set the width of a select to the same as the other inputs in a form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the example below I define two forms side by side. I have a select drop down with an option that makes it larger than the other inputs and it spills over the boundary of the form. Is there I way I can specify that the select should be the same width as all the other inputs? I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<div class="container">
       <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                   <form class="well form-horizontal">
                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine1" name="addressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine2" name="addressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State/Province/Region</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="state" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                                  <select class="selectpicker">
                                     <option>A really long option to push the menu over the edget</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </fieldset>
                   </form>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1">
                   <form class="well form-horizontal">
                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine1" name="addressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine2" name="addressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State/Province/Region</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="state" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                                  <select class="selectpicker">
                                     <option>A really long option to push the menu over the edget</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </fieldset>
                   </form>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: add class to your select tag `<select class="selectpicker form-control">`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of css in your custom css file and you can change the style of select tag or just put a
class="selectpicker form-control" in your select tag

```css
select {
position:relative; 
width:100%;
height:34px;
color:#666;
background:transparent;
font-size: 12px; 
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                   <form class="well form-horizontal">
                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine1" name="addressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine2" name="addressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State/Province/Region</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="state" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                                  <select class="selectpicker">
                                     <option>A really long option to push the menu over the edget</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </fieldset>
                   </form>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1">
                   <form class="well form-horizontal">
                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine1" name="addressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address Line 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine2" name="addressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State/Province/Region</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="state" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                                  <select class="selectpicker">
                                     <option>A really long option to push the menu over the edget</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </fieldset>
                   </form>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Add this in your custom css file it will work